# Error with pictures and 'if' in Python TelegramBot. How to fix?

Tags: python, if-statement, photo, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am using `pyTelegramBotAPI` and `Python 3.7`.

Bot in general works but an error occurs when the BOT should send the photo. When I write a bot message, in answer to which he must send a photo or a sticker, it goes but when next you enter the same command the bot sends nothing. I am a newbie so please suggest me how can I better write this code.

```
elif instead of if isn't working.
```

...

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])

def bot_messages(message):
    if message.text.lower() == "Привет".lower():
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Ку! ✋. Напиши /welcome.")

    if message.text.lower() == "/welcome".lower():
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я бот Римуру. Напиши название животного, например, 'кот', и я отправлю его картинку.")
        bot.send_sticker(message.from_user.id, sticker1)

    if message.text.lower() == "питон".lower():
        bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo1)
    if message.text.lower() == "мышь".lower():
        bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo2)
    if message.text.lower() == "кот".lower():
        bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo3)
    if message.text.lower() == "жираф".lower():
```

...

Comment: could you please provide us with error, when the bot sends the photo ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/Ef2iVVo

Comment: it seems that you're uploading a non existing photo, since the error says 'file must be non empty' please check the photo object if it's null or not, try to visualize it using matplot or opencv

Comment: Thank you so much . I think I understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

write this code if this code does not work, please enclose the code at https://pastebin.com and tell us its location.

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def main(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    text = str(message.text).decode("utf-8").lower()
    if text == "привет":
        bot.send_message(user_id, "Ку! ✋. Напиши /welcome.")
    if text == "/welcome":
        bot.send_message(user_id, "Я бот Римуру. Напиши название животного, например, 'кот', и я отправлю его картинку.")
    if text == "питон":
        bot.send_photo(user_id, 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/python-snake-450w-184814297.jpg')
    if text == "мышь":
        bot.send_photo(user_id, 'https://mysekret.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/5-47.jpg')
    if text == "кот":
        bot.send_photo(user_id, 'https://pp.userapi.com/c845122/v845122166/10ba66/gVecT_orwwY.jpg')
```

Comment: Thank you too. When you enter the Internet link everything works fine.

Comment: Does the image file from the computer memory or print out an image file sent to a bot?